# Siege engines range

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

In ESO we have ballistas, catapults, trebuchets, rams and oil pots. Leaving the last 2 out (for obvious reasons) I'm having troubles to determine the average range for each of them. Also, is that range affected by the PVP range passive (can't remember the exact name of the skill)?

It seems that trebuchets have the longest range, then catapults, then ballistas, but by how much do they outrange each other?

I'm asking because I had some interesting cases when I could not hit a player with a catapult but he could hit me with a ballista. I thought it was because of the passive (I had only level 1 on that char). But really... less than 2m difference?

Then I had some cases when a player could hit me with a ballista from the wall and I could not reach him with a trebuchet (this time I had passive maxed) so that made me wonder... does elevation influence range (realistically it should)?

If the projectile is realistic then all I need to find out is its initial speed (then I can compute max range including elevation factor). Is there any way I can find this out?

If there is a fixed range and elevation does not influence it, what are the ranges for each war machine?

Answer (score 2):

The range is physically correct. So if you are on a higher ground, you can actually shoot further. This is why you always want to siege from higher ground. The enemy ballistas can make it extraordinary difficult since they - obviously - always have higher grounds.

Comment: Any way I can find out the projectile speed?

Comment: @zozo There are no informations about projectile speeds. Actually, there are NO information about ANYTHING. ZOS obviously has some kind of embargo on any information which would let you theorycraft anything. Most information are obtained through observing.